# onClick hideKeyboard crashes that app when edittext is not selected

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to implement a feature where the virtual keyboard disappears from view when the user touches outside of it. It works, but when the edittext is not selected it causes the app to crash. I tried using a try/catch but that didn't help. From what I can tell, it's trying to close the keyboard when no keyboard is open. Any suggestions?

In the XML file:

```
android:onClick="hideKeyboard"
```

In the Java file:

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace you code

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

with:

```
InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view3=getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view3==null){
            view3=new View(this);
        }
        assert imm != null;
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view3.getWindowToken(), 0);
```